# On embeddings of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the same image

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-functions

Given $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ which are smooth embeddings with the same image, does there exist a diffeomorphism $h \in \mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $f=g\circ h$?

What I want is an equivalence relation between embeddings with the same image. If there is no such equivalence, so be it.

I did see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402397/do-two-embeddings-of-a-euclidean-space-into-a-higher-dimensional-one-only-differ), but I'm interested in precomposition.

Comment: What are your own thoughts? What did you try?

Comment: I'm not well versed in differential geometry, so not much. It may simply be the case that this question has a trivial answer; I just couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you try to compose some obvious maps?

Comment: If, to make the images the same, we select $f$ as the trivial embedding, then the image of $f$ is essentially $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well and I think my claim holds. This feels hand-wavy though

Comment: I would not say your method is "hand-wavy", instead I would say that it is "invalid". You are not free to "select" $f$ as the trivial embedding: the maps $f$ and $g$ are given to you.